# How to unzip/decompress a *.z file

Tags: python, zip

I have a file called pack.z which contains a few file. I want to unzip/decompress this pack.z file into a folder named *./pack using a python script. 
I have tried using zipfile module, but it throws an error **"zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file"**
So I am looking for a method to unzip this file. Any help would be great.

Comment: The first thing would be to identity the real format of your file. The `.z` extension seems to be generated from `pack` or maybe `compress`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pack_%28compression%29 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compress

Comment: @Cilyan...it's a .z file and not .Z file.

Comment: @Cilyan....i can extract by right clicking it and then choosing extract to a folder option.

Comment: Most compressed formats include a few magic bytes at the start. I would check your file against this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures to see if you can't find definitively what it's compressed as.

Comment: @DanLecocq.....how do i find magic number of my file?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to unzip .z file, the following code snippet work:

```
//os.mkdir(path of the new folder )    
unzip_cmd_str = r"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" + " x " + path of file to be unzipped + " *.* " + path where to store unzip file
subprocess.call(unzip_cmd_str)
```

Here we use the winrar tool to unzip through subprocess call from script.
 NOTE: If you want to store the unzip file in a folder that doesn't exist before unzipping, you have to create that folder first using os.mkdir and then use the path of the new folder in the unzip_cmd_str.